# Get to work with the authenticated guard in laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, laravel-middleware

I have a session login system for a few guards. I'm using Vue a lot and I came to the point where I need authentication in Vue in order to fetch and post data properly. The question is how could I get the authenticated session user to work with API. So in api.php I want to use a controller whose Middleware the authenticated user. I don't want to use Passport because I only have logins over the webpage and not API.

Answer (score 0):

vue supports component also there is something called props which they are data that you can pass to your vue component what I would usually do is pass the authenticated user id to my vue component and then when I ever fire a request from vue component I will pass the current authenticated user to the backend and there I check if the id received with request is the same as the current authenticated user.

check the example below I will use the regular guard

loading vue component from blade

```
//loading vue test-component and pass the authenticated user 
<test-component :authuser="{{Auth::(user)->id}}"></test-component>
```

vue component

```
<script>
export default {
    props : ['authuser'], //should be the same name as you passed it
    data(){
        return {

        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.post('/api/test' , {
             'authuser' : this.authuser
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {

        });
    }
}
```

Api route

```
use Auth;

Route::post('api/test' , function($request){
    if(Auth::user()->id == $request->authuser)
       return 'you are authenticated';
    else 
       return 'you are not authenticated';
});
```

Hope you find this helpful , Good luck.

Comment: Oh that was a good example, thanks for the effort!
Though it is not quite what I want. In my controller I should use a middleware so I can't get the current authenticated guard. I am using ```Hesto/multi-auth``` Whenever I set a constructor I get unauthenticated error, even if I set the specific guard in the constructor

Comment: You are welcome well in this case I think you can use the same thing above with the use of request classed so you can still use the middleware on your class and do the check for is authenticated in the request class in authorize method you can make use of the Auth facade there try that